# How to change 'is required' field in Bundle Items on frontend

Tags: bundled-product

1) I have a combination of product i.e. Product A + Product B both will be bought together and cannot be sold individually.

2) Once customer purchases above bundle product of combination Product A + Product B on the repurchasing of same product again the customer should be able to buy Product A and leave Product B means they can be sold individually.

How can this be achieved?

Many thanks